# Selenium: File not downloading even though button element exists, button is being clicked, and download dialogue is opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the **Export Data** button on [this FanGraphs webpage](https://fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards) using `selenium`. When clicked, the button starts a file download, which exports the data in the table as a CSV file. The following three code snippets all belong to the same class.

### Remote Browser Setup

```py
class ExportData:

    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        options.headless = False
        os.makedirs("out", exist_ok=True)
        preferences = {
            "browser.download.folderList": 2,
            "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting": False,
            "browser.download.dir": os.path.abspath("out"),
            "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "text/csv"
        }
        for pref in preferences:
            options.set_preference(pref, preferences[pref])
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

### Attempt 1

```py
class ExportData:

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def export(self, name="test.csv"):
        elem = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name(
            "data-export"
        )
        while True:
            try:
                elem.click()
                break
           except exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
                return
        os.rename(
            os.path.join("out", "Splits Leaderboard Data.csv"),
            os.path.join("out", name)
        )
```

### Attempt 2

```py
class ExportData:

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def export(self, name="test.csv"):
        while True:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(
                    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(
                        (By.CLASS_NAME, "data-export")
                    )
                ).click()
                break
           except exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
                return
        os.rename(
            os.path.join("out", "Splits Leaderboard Data.csv"),
            os.path.join("out", name)
        )
```

However, when I call the `export()` function, on the `os.rename()` call, I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'out\\Splits Leaderboard Data.csv' -> 'out\\test.csv'`

### Export Data Element

```
<a class="data-export" href="data:application/csv;charse..." download="Splits Leaderboard Data .csv">Export Data</a>
```

I have written multiple tests for this function and I have confirmed with `BeautifulSoup4` that the selector `a[class='data-export']` selects the above element. I also switched `headless=False`, and I see the file download dialogue open, but the file itself does not download.

So the issue is that the button is being clicked and the file dialogue is being opened, however the file is not being downloaded.

Comment: It'll take a certain amount of time to download the file.  It doesn't look like you are waiting at all.  Some browsers will use a temporary name with a ".crdownload" extension and then rename that when the download is complete.

Comment: @pcalkins I checked the element and it has a ridiculously long link which, if clicked, creates a **download** file in my *Downloads* directory (since it's a manual click). However, I don't see the same when I run my tests.

Comment: sounds like you aren't waiting for the download headers to be sent...  if you keep clicking a new header will be sent... (and depending on the way the site works they may not have concurrent downloads functionality... they would need multiple hidden iframes for that to work on the same page...)

Comment: @pcalkins I just stuck the whole element-clicking code inside a `while` loop, looping until the path to the file exists. I let it run for a good 10 minutes, but the loop never ended.

Comment: because it keeps clicking... that'll keep generating a new download header, interrupting the previous... the last click should work, but since it's infinite you'll have a problem.  What you want to do is wait until the file shows up in the dir.  (just check name, not extension since some browsers will add .crdownload... OR just add a sleep... it shouldn't take long for the download to begin)  Then at the end, you must wait until all downloads are complete before quitting the webdriver/browser. (the real filename/complete file appears...)

Comment: if you're fast enough you can replicate manually... click to download a file, and before the download begins, click to download the file or another file again.  You'll see that only the last file will download. (if the site hasn't implemented concurrent downloads, which most don't)